# How to reverse last N elements of list in python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list:

```
>>> numbers = list(range(1, 15))

>>> numbers

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

I need reverse last 10 element only using slice notation

At first, I try just slice w/o reverse

```
>>> numbers[-10:]

[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Then:

`>>> numbers[-10::-1]`

I expected  `[14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]`

but got `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.

I can solve the problem like this:

`numbers[-10:][::-1]`

and everything OK

`[14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]`

But I wondering why  `numbers[-10::-1]` doesn't work as expected in my case and if there a way to get the right result by one slice?

Comment: Something is weird in your example because as written, `numbers` holds the integers from 1 to 14, but excluding 15.

Answer (score 12):

> **Is there a way to get the right result by one slice?**

Well, you can easily get right result by one slicing with code below:

```
numbers[:-11:-1]
# [14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
```

> **Why  numbers[-10::-1] doesn't work as expected?**

Well it's work as expected, see enumerating of all slicing possibilities in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509377/2067976) of [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) question. See quoting ( from answer i've pointed above) of expected behaviour for your use case below:

```
seq[low::stride] =>>> # [seq[low], seq[low+stride], ..., seq[-1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

is that what you are looking for?

```
numbers = list(range(1, 15))
numbers[:-11:-1]
# [14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
```

`slice.indices` 'explains':

```
print(slice(None, -11, -1).indices(len(numbers)))
# (13, 3, -1)
```

meaning that

```
numbers[:-11:-1] == numbers[13:3:-1]
```

Comment: protoganist In your example sliced only 9 element, but I got it `numbers[:-10:-1]` thank you

Comment: @EugeneAlkhouski: ok, fixed. your examples were not very consistent which left me confused... :)